# javascript select the second option automatically?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use javascript, to automatically select Option value 2?
But I have  and  as the same id ..

```js
var index = 1; /* option do select*/
document.getElementById("594951-Cor").options.selectedIndex = index;
```

```html
<div id="594951-Cor" name="594951-Cor">

<select id="594951-Cor" name="594951-Cor" class="">
<option value="0">Selecione...</option>
<option value="1">Color 01</option>
<option value="2">Color 02</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: You have 2 elements with the same ID, and the `document.getElementById` returns the first. That is not a valid HTML! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After solve the problem with ID's (change the duplicated id's), if you want to select by value, just assign on the `select` node:

```
document.getElementById("594951-Cor").value = "2";
```

assuming that you want to select `<option value="2">Color 02</option>` and the `id` of the `select` node is `"594951-Cor"`.

The `"2"` is the value of the `option, not the index.

Comment: I can't change the div id, because I use a shopify theme and I can't access the code, for that reason I would like to develop the code in javascript.
Because this change via html is easier.

is there a way to select only the id of the select?

Comment: If the structure will be always that (DIV and then SELECT), you can use `document.getElementById("594951-Cor").children[0]` to get the `SELECT` node. Other alternative is to use `document.querySelector("select#594951-Cor")`, but will not work since the ID must start with letter.